# Tkinter making image variable into a class

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I was making a game recently using `tkinter` and it's `Canvas` widget, but ran into a problem when trying to move an image. I set the `canvas.create_image` to a variable called `character` but noticed it turned it into an object. This causes issues as when I try and use the `canvas.move(character)`, it comes back with "`character` not defined". Here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pygame
import threading
import time


gamestate= 'title'
waiting = False

#window init
root = Tk()
WIDTH=1280
HEIGHT=720
canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='black')
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
logo = PhotoImage(file='Ghost clipart.png')
root.iconphoto(False, logo)

#setting up all the images
title_image = PhotoImage(file='title.png')
board_image = Image.open('board.png')
done_board = board_image.resize((1920,1080), Image.ANTIALIAS)
board_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(done_board)
character_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='first_run_left.png')

#display the title screen
def title_screen():
    title = canvas.create_image(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2, anchor=CENTER, image=title_image)

#define the events after clicking play
def play():
    canvas.delete("all")
    board = canvas.create_image(WIDTH/2 + 100,HEIGHT/2 - 360, anchor=CENTER, image=board_image)
    character = canvas.create_image(556,304,anchor=CENTER,image=character_image)

#testing for what should happen the the mouse button is clicked
def click(event):
    if gamestate == 'title':
        print(event.x, event.y)
        if event.x > 475 and event.x < 804 and event.y > 213 and event.y < 337:
            play()
        elif event.x > 475 and event.x < 804 and event.y > 404 and event.y < 527:
            print("skin")

def up(event):
    canvas.move(character,0,10)


root.bind('<Button-1>', click)
root.bind('<Up>', up)
#audio module
def test_loop():
    while True:
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load("nokia-ringtone-arabic.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(23)

thread = threading.Thread(target=test_loop)
thread.daemon = True 
thread.start()



title_screen()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code you posted in this question. We do not need 5 different image files (not provided), or `pygame` sound mixer to answer a question about images; further, the variable `character` is not defined and the code cannot run! Here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that uses the arrow keys to move an image on the canvas. Note that the variable `img` (in your case `character`) must be accessible from the functions that act upon it, therefore its scope must be above these functions.

You can use this as a starting point to solve your problem.

image used:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk


def up(event):
    canvas.move(img, 0, -10)

def down(event):
    canvas.move(img, 0, 10)

def left(event):
     canvas.move(img, -10, 0)

def right(event):
    canvas.move(img, 10, 0)

width = 500
height = 500

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Moving image")
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
my_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="pix.png")
img = canvas.create_image(260, 125, anchor=tk.NW, image=my_image)

window.bind("<Up>", up)
window.bind("<Down>", down)
window.bind("<Left>", left)
window.bind("<Right>", right)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `character` is a local variable inside `play()` function, it cannot be accessed inside `up()` function.

However you can use `tags` option of `create_image()`:

```py
def play():
    ...
    canvas.create_image(556,304,anchor=CENTER,image=character_image, tags='character')
```

Then you can refer to that image item using the same tag:

```py
def up(event):
    canvas.move('character',0,-10) # use tag 'character'
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i realized that i didn't global the `character` variable, but in my case it isn't a variable, but rather a object inside a class, im not sure why and i can't change it. But i think the `tags` will work anyway, so it isn't a problem anymore. Edit - The `tags` function has worked and the program now runs as intended, thank you.

Comment: `create_image()` returns an integer ID, not an object inside a class.

Comment: visual studio marks `character` as an object, and turns it cyan.

Comment: See [doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method).  And you can also run `print(type(character))` and it returns `<class 'int'>`.

Answer (score 0):

`create_image` doesn't turn anything into an object. It simply returns an integer identifier. The original object is unchanged. `character` is undefined because it's a local variable and thus only visible in the method that created it.